# How to listen variable change in getx and push new page?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I have a `StatusManger` which has a timer to count down:

```dart
class StatusManager extends GetxController {
  factory StatusManager() => _getInstance();
  static StatusManager? _instance;

  Timer? _timer;
  var count = 60.obs;

  static _getInstance() {
    if (_instance == null) {
      _instance = StatusManager._();
    }
    return _instance;
  }

  StatusManager._() {}

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    debugPrint('onInit');
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    debugPrint('onClose');
    super.onClose();
  }

  startTimer() {
    stopTimer();

    _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t) {
      fetchStatus();
    });
  }

  stopTimer() {
    _timer?.cancel();
  }

  fetchStatus() async {
    count--;
  }
}
```

Now, in some widget, I wanna listen the remaining time and push to a new page.
I don't use the `count` to build widget, I just listen the count value changed.

How can I to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I fix this by

```dart
Obx(() {
Future(() async {
  if (statusManager.count.value == 0) {
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this functionality by using **Getx Worker** like this:

```
class StatusManager extends GetxController {
  
  var count = 60.obs;
  Worker? listenerWorker;
  
  @override
  void onInit() async {
    super.onInit();
    listenerWorker = ever(count, (callback) {
      print("count: $callback ");
      // if(callback == 52){
      // add your logic or call related function here
      // }
    });
  }
  
  @override
  void onClose() async {
    listenerWorker?.dispose();
    super.onClose();
  }
  
}
```

Comment: How can I listen this in widget? The logic could be different in widgets.

Comment: You can listen to the `worker` in your widgets `onInit` function.

Comment: Could be more specific？Stateful widget have no `onInit` function

Comment: Stateful widgets do have `initState` method you can use that for listening the change of variable.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know how to do this in `initState`...

Answer (score 0):

you can try the below simple way that you can create a global variable to detect the time is end, for example:

create a global variable class

```
class Global {
   static RxBool isEndTime = false.obs;
}
```

and update this flag in your `StatusManager`

```
startTimer() {
    stopTimer();

    _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t) {
      fetchStatus();
    });
  }

  fetchStatus() async {
    count--;
    if(count == 0){
      Global.isEndTime.value = true;  //update to end time
    }
  }
```

and check it in another widget

```
if(Global.isEndTime.value) {
    Global.isEndTime.value = false; //reset the value
    Get.to(() => OtherPage());
  }
```

Comment: The problem is that how can I check in another widget. I got `The following assertion was thrown building Obx(has builder, dirty, state: ObxState#3999c):
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.`

Comment: have you called the setState() during build? if you are using Obx, then don't need to use setState()